# spring boot: chain application properties from a starter?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm developing a spring boot app and starter.  I want the starter to hold common properties and code.

In my starter I have an application-dev.properties file.  I have defined a @Profile("dev") in the starter.

When I start my app using the dev profile I see properties from the starter, which is great.  What's not great is when I add an application-dev.properties file to my app, the one from the starter is no longer read at all.  This means I can't figure out how to put common "dev" profile properties in there.

Based on the [external configuration](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config) documentation I assumed this would work because the starter file would be read and then the app file.

> Spring Boot uses a very particular PropertySource order that is designed to allow sensible overriding of values. Properties are considered in the following order:
>
> SNIP
>
> Profile-specific application properties outside of your packaged jar (application-{profile}.properties and YAML variants)
>
> Profile-specific application properties packaged inside your jar (application-{profile}.properties and YAML variants)

Any suggestions?

Comment: A suggestion. How about putting application-dev.properties into src/main/resources/config folder for your starter and putting application-dev.properties of your app into src/main/resources?

Comment: That worked!  I'll mark this answered if you reply instead of adding a comment.  thx!

Comment: Are these properties you are discussed placed on the starter module or the autoconfigure one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Putting application-dev.properties into src/main/resources/config folder for your starter and putting application-dev.properties of your app into src/main/resources should help resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think adding `application-dev.properties` to starter is not good idea. The problem is you can add the file only once. Well, you may put the file into folder `config`. It means you can add the file at most twice. No more. What if you decide to use second starter; where you put `application-dev.properties` then?

I think `application*.properties` should be added to end user product only. For portable module I propose to use

> 16. @PropertySource annotations on your @Configuration classes.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:/my/starter/dev.properties")
@Profile("dev")
public class MyConf {}
```